# How to check 504 error in the api site by cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am in trouble due to this 504 error in my api requested server.I am using this code to fetch api data

```
    $api_url="*****";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
    $parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json);
```

Comment: 504 is a timeout. The server takes too long to process and it dies.

Comment: Yes, You are right. My client using api in this page - [train running status](https://trainsrunningstatus.net/running-status) and due to this google webmaster show server 504 error in all page.
please help me if somebody can do it.

Comment: Is it your own API, or a third party one?

Comment: It is 3rd party API

Comment: Hmm, that makes things a little more difficult. It's their error, not yours. :-(

Comment: Yes, I want to skip that if it load more time due to 504 error

Comment: I would contact them, and send them a copy of the request you made and the response you received.

Answer (score 3):

`$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //check if 504 return.`

Sometimes I would check if the code returns 200 as a normal respond.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
$api_url="****";
$t = microtime( TRUE );
file_get_contents($api_url);
$t = microtime( TRUE ) - $t;
if($t<=5){
Execute curl here
}
```